# Movement speed varies?

Tags: java, 2d, game-physics

Hey guys on my 2D game the movement speed varies.. I was making my game on my Desktop and it ran fine but then I went on my laptop and the Player moved slower then the Desktop.

Here is my current game loop:

```
    public void gameLoop() throws IOException {

    isRunning = true;


    while(isRunning == true) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics();
        //main game loop
        //updates everything and draws
        //main componenets
        //e.g. Player
        // clear the screen
        g2d.setColor(Color.lightGray);
        g2d.fillRect(0,0,640,496);

        //drawing
        player.paint(g2d);//paint player
        map.paint(g2d);//paint each wall in wall list

        g2d.dispose();
        strategy.show();

        //update
        try { player.updateMovement(); } catch (Exception e) {};

        try { Thread.sleep(4); } catch (Exception e) {};


    }
}
```

Here is my player.updateMovement() method:

```
    public void updateMovement() {

    if(!down || !up) {
        ny = 0;
    }

    if(!left || !right) {
        nx = 0;
    }

    if(left) {
        nx = -1;
    }

    if(right) {
        nx = 1;
    }

    if(up) {
        ny = -1;
    }

    if(down) {
        ny = 1;
    }



if ((nx != 0) || (ny != 0)) {
    x += nx;
    y += ny;
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a fixed-rate drawing loop: every iteration should last the same, and if there is some time left, sleep that amount of time. For instance, if we fix a period of 41.6 ms (which is 24 fps), and a certain iteration lasts 20 ms, then you should sleep 41.6 - 20 = 21.6 ms that pass.

If your code is too heavy to run in that time on a low end PC, then you can increase the period so that every machine can cope with it.

By the way, you could also optimize your code.

You can find more information on gaming.stackexange.com

Comment: Everything that doesn't change between iterations can be placed outside of the while loop. For instance, creation of objects is "expensive". I'm thinking on creating that `Graphics2D` outside the while, then clearing it and updating inside the loop, instead of creating a new instance. You could also modify the `player.updateMovement()` method to not to throw exceptions, so that you can get rid of that try-catch. In general, avoid creating new objects (instead try to reuse them) and use primitives instead of wrappers (int better than Integer).

Comment: Thanks believe I have cleaned it up a bit.